# JSON.parse unexpected token multidimensional array

Tags: php, ajax, json, token

Hello I have simple question. I have some data fetched from database and json encoded and sent to html file over AJAX from PHP script. I want to JSON parse that data. Data looks like this:

[image]

And in PHP file like this:

```
$profesors = array
                (
                'id' => ($id),
                'name' => ($profesor)
                );
```

When I try to JSON parse it with JSON.parse() command I get "unexpected token {". Does anyone have some suggestion what to do? Also if it would be easier for achieving my goal I can use some other data type than array I am using, if someone knows better way...

EDIT

my PHP code that generates 2d array

```
<?php
$var=$_POST["oblast"];
$connection = mysql_connect('localhost','root','pass');
if (!$connection) {die("not successfull" . mysql_error());}

$result = mysql_query('set character set utf8', $connection); 
$result = mysql_query('set names utf8', $connection);
$db_select = mysql_select_db("fakultet",$connection);
$brojac=0;
$profesor="";
//$data = array(array());
$queryData = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM predmet WHERE idpred = '$var'");
while($result1 = mysql_fetch_array($queryData))
{
$prof=$result1['idprof'];
    $queryData1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM profesori WHERE idprof = '$prof'");
        while($result2 = mysql_fetch_array($queryData1))
        {

            $id=$result2['idprof'];
            $profesor=$result2['ime']." ".$result2['prezime'];
            $profesors = array
                (
                'id' => ($id),
                'name' => ($profesor)
                );

            echo json_encode($profesors);

        }
    //echo($result1['idprof']);
    //$data[]=$result['idprof'];

}

//echo "$data";
?>
```

Comment: That's not valid JSON.  It should probably be something like `[{}, {}]`.  How are creating/echoing it?  You should be creating the structure you want, then calling `json_encode` *once* (and only once).

Comment: ahh, I understand...I have uploaded my code that generates it,, so I would be really glad if you can check it

Comment: I made it, just added [] after $profesors and moved echo json_encode($profesors); outside of while loop, thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing `echo json_encode($profesors);` *inside* your `while` loop.  Don't do that.  You should only ever call `json_encode` *once*.

Try something like this:

```
$profesors = array();

while($result2 = mysql_fetch_array($queryData1))
{
    $id=$result2['idprof'];
    $profesor=$result2['ime']." ".$result2['prezime'];
    $profesors[] = array(
        'id' => $id,
        'name' => $profesor
    );
}

echo json_encode($profesors);
```

Answer (score 1):

The unexpected token is the second opening curly brace. It's expecting one object because there are no array brackets.  Either have your response look like this:

```
[{
    "id"   : "1",
    "name" : "Ivan Nikolaj"
 },
 {
    "id"   : "2",
    "name" : "Zdravko Topic"
 }]
```

or this :

```
{
   "id"   : "1",
   "name" : "Ivan Nikolaj"
}
```

or even better, this:

```
 {
     "status"   : 200,
     "response" : [
         {
             "id"   : 1,
             "name" : "Ivan Nikolaj"
         },
         {
             "id"   : 2,
             "name" : "Zdravko Topic"
         }
     ]
 }
```